# TTF_RenderText_Solid(...) causes segmentation fault error

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

I'm trying to utilize a class `Text` to handle with text in my c++ SDL2-based program.

TTF_RenderText_Solid works perfectly in the main function, although in my classe `Text`, in this line here `SDL_Surface *surface = TTF_RenderText_Solid( font, text.c_str(), fg );`, it's causing some errors. Sometimes it gives me a segmentation fault error, sometimes it didn't.

I debugged the code and all the three variables, `TTF_Font *font`, `std::string text` and `SDL_Color fg`, were with theirs respective correct values.

My main function:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>

#include "Text.h"

int main()
{
    try
    {
        SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO );
        TTF_Init();

        SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow( "Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 800, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
        SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer( window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED );


        TTF_Font *f = TTF_OpenFont( "cruft.ttf", 32 );
        SDL_Surface *s = TTF_RenderText_Solid( f, "Avocado", {0,0,0,255} );
        if(s == NULL)
            std::cout << "s == NULL\n";



        Text title;
        title = Text( renderer, "cruft.ttf", 32, "title" );
        title.render_Text_Solid( "Avocado", {0,0,0,255} );



        SDL_Quit();
        TTF_Quit();

        return 0;
    }
    catch( std::exception& e )
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << "\n";
        return 0;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cerr << "Unkown error!\n";
        return 0;
    }
}
```

My `Text.cpp` file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

#include "Text.h"
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>

//Constructors
Text::Text(){}

Text::Text(SDL_Renderer *renderer, std::string file, int ptsize, std::string name)
{
    set_renderer( renderer );
    this->name = name;

    set_TTF_Font( file, ptsize );
}

Text::~Text()
{
    TTF_CloseFont( font );
    SDL_DestroyTexture( texture );
}



void Text::set_renderer( SDL_Renderer *renderer )
{
    if( renderer == NULL )
        throw std::runtime_error( name + ": Renderer could not be set! renderer == NULL\n" + SDL_GetError() );

    this->renderer = renderer;
}

void Text::set_TTF_Font( std::string file, int ptsize )
{
    TTF_CloseFont( font );
    font = NULL;
    SDL_DestroyTexture( texture );
    texture = NULL;
    width = 0;
    height = 0;

    if( file == "" )
        throw std::runtime_error( name + ": TTF_Font* could not be set! file == ""\n" + SDL_GetError() );
    if( ptsize <= 0 )
        throw std::runtime_error( name + ": TTF_Font* could not be set! ptsize <= 0\n" + SDL_GetError() );

    TTF_Font *font = TTF_OpenFont( file.c_str(), ptsize );

    if( font == NULL )
        throw std::runtime_error( name + ": TTF_Font* could not be set! font == NULL\n" + SDL_GetError() );

    this->font = font;
}

void Text::render_Text_Solid( std::string text, SDL_Color fg )
{
    SDL_DestroyTexture( texture );
    texture = NULL;
    width = 0;
    height = 0;

    SDL_Surface *surface = TTF_RenderText_Solid( font, text.c_str(), fg );

    if( surface == NULL )
        throw std::runtime_error( name + ": Text could not be created! surface == NULL\n" + SDL_GetError() );

    texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface( renderer, surface );
    width = surface->w;
    height = surface->h;
    SDL_FreeSurface( surface );

    if( texture == NULL )
        throw std::runtime_error( name + ": Text could not be created! texture == NULL\n" + SDL_GetError() );
}
```

My `Text.h` file:

```
#ifndef TEXT_H_INCLUDED
#define TEXT_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>

class Text
{
    public:

    //constructors
    Text();
    Text(SDL_Renderer *renderer, std::string file, int ptsize, std::string name);
    ~Text();

    void set_renderer( SDL_Renderer *renderer );
    void set_TTF_Font( std::string file, int ptsize );
    void render_Text_Solid( std::string text, SDL_Color fg );

    //render
    void render( int x, int y );
    void render( SDL_Rect *srcrect, SDL_Rect *dstrect );

    //variables
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;

    private:
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = NULL;
    SDL_Texture *texture = NULL;
    TTF_Font *font = NULL;
    std::string name = "";

};

#endif // TEXT_H_INCLUDED
```

PS: I utilizing Manjaro Linux and Codeblocks

Comment: Can you share more details about the error?

Comment: @NicoHaase details about the error added, thanks for trying to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first look at what these lines do:

```
    Text title;
    title = Text( renderer, "cruft.ttf", 32, "title" );
```

First you create `title`, and initialise it with default constructor `Text::Text()`, which sets default values to its fields. Then you create a second `Text` (let's call it `title1` for clarity) object with specialised constructor. Then you copy `title1` to `title` - since no `operator=` is defined, default copy is generated. Now your `title` have the same values as `title1`. And `title1.~Text()` is invoked, killing your `font`.

What you have is your `title.font` still having its previous value, but it points to already closed font structure.

That could be avoided by not constructing temporary `Text` object - e.g. `Text title = Text(.......)` will not produce temporary object and copying. That's just a workaround, actual problem remains - your `Text` objects cannot be safely copied. There are many ways to approach this problem - like using some sort of `unique_ptr` wrappers or dropping destructors in favor of manual deinit method, etc..

Which brings us to next problem - if you solve your copying, you now can generate text surface and texture, but look at your exit code:

```
    Text title;
    // ... omitted
    SDL_Quit();
    TTF_Quit();
    return 0;
```

You have your finalisation in reverse - you want to close font, drop textures, destroy renderer/window, *then* call `TTF_Quit` and `SDL_Quit`, but instead you have `SDL_Quit()`, `TTF_Quit()`, and only after that `title.~Text()` - will'll probably crash because SDL/TTF already finalised and you're not supposed to perform SDL calls after that. Of course that could also be solved, e.g. by enclosing your `title` into extra code block, but the amount of things to watch for becoming too large.